# Siri cannot access my Appliaction data to do the tasks

Tags: objective-c, ios11, siri, sirikit

I am developing a Siri enabled (Payments Domain) Application. 
If I open my application first time and do not answer the Siri Authorization pop-up and say "**Hey Siri send money with my 'Application Name'**", Siri answers as "**I need to access your 'Application Name' data to do this. Is that OK?**" with NO & YES buttons.

After that there happens two different results according to my answer by **speech** or by **touching the button**;

1. If I answer by touching the button, Siri can continue the operations.

2. If I answer by speech, Siri gives error as "**'My Name', we've had a problem. Please try again.**"

I put the Siri Authorization code as below;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Other codes here
    // ....

    // Ask Siri Authorization now

    [INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:^(INSiriAuthorizationStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"SiriKit | Siri Authorization status %ld", (long)status);
    }];
}
```

Is there any idea why I got the second problem?

Comment: I suppose the problem may be related with the development provisioning profiles Apple Siri bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the lines of code in the app that asks if the user wants to enable Siri (as it is a privacy feature), and have you enabled it **and** made sure that your plist contains the Siri privacy usage description line?

**Edit:** When you click the button, you are not using your voice to send data to the app, and therefore no privacy-invasive function is used, so the button does not need authorisation to carry out operations.

When you respond by speech, Siri will not process the information you have given, as it invades privacy where permission has not been given.

I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: Yes I did all. I also mentioned that the problem is reproducable in only a specific scenerio as I mentioned, I explained that in my question.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I overlooked your question. I have edited my answer to provide a reason why.

Comment: You thought as me :), but when I looked into the other application belongs to another person/company it works with speech too. I thought they did extra work to fix it or the Appstore provisioning profiles of Siri works like that